# AWS S3 IAM Permission to download only from subfolder based on the name of the subfolder (not the path)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Story: "As a user responsible for issuing refunds, I would like to be able to download from any AWS s3 folder that contains the name 'New Sales File'"

This is the first time I've needed to do a wildcard at the start of a prefix. What should this prefix line be: "s3:prefix": "*/*/New Sales File/*"

Full policy is below. [DELETED represents sensitive information that I removed -- values don't match pattern]

```
{
  "Statement": [
{
  "Action": [
    "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::*"
  ]
},
{
  "Action": [
    "s3:ListBucket"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::DELETED"
  ]
},
{
  "Action": [
    "s3:Get*"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::DELETED"
  ],
  "Condition" : {
    "StringLike": {
      "s3:prefix": "*/*/New Sales File/*"
    },
    "StringEquals": {
      "s3:delimeter": "/"
    }
  }
},
{
  "Action": [
    "s3:*"
  ],
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::DELETED"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
      "s3:prefix": "*/*/DELETED/"
    },
    "StringEquals": {
      "s3:delimiter": "/"
    }
  }
},
{
  "Action": [
    "s3:*"
  ],
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::DELETED"
  ],
  "Condition": {
    "NotIpAddress": {
      "aws:SourceIp": "DELETED"
    }
  }
}
```

]
}